# factory_girl_rails 4.1.0 in rails 3.2 environment produces 'Factory not registered: user'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I am a factory_girl noob and have not been able to determine why the Factory is not 'registered'. Not sure where it is registered.

relevant portion of Gemfile:

```
...
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'launchy'
end
...
```

relevant portion of config/application.rb:

```
...
module Appname
  class Application < Rails::Application
    ...
    config.generators do |g|
      g.test_framework :rspec,
        :fixtures => true,
        :view_specs => false,
        :helper_specs => false,
        :routing_specs => true,
        :controller_specs => true,
        :request_specs => true
      g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, :dir => "spec/factories"
    end
    ...
  end
end
```

relevant portion of spec/models/user_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  it "has a valid factory" do
    FactoryGirl.create(:user).should be_valid
  end
  ...
end
```

result of $rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb:

```
Failures:

  1) User has a valid factory
     Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.create(:user).should be_valid
     ArgumentError:
       Factory not registered: user
```

---

UPDATE:

spec/factories/users.rb:

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :contact do |f|
    f.first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
    f.last_name { Faker::Name.last_name }
    f.email { Faker::Internet.email }
    f.password { Faker::Name.last_name }
    f.password_confirmation { Faker::Name.last_name }
  end
end
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you created a factory for users? Something like `FactoryGirl.define { factory :user ... }`. Ref: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/wiki/Usage

Comment: @shioyama, thanks. I updated the question with the factory. Sorry I left it out.

Comment: @shioyama, I'll try to create a standard one without Faker data to see if that will get it to pass.

Comment: It's not the Faker data that's the problem, it's the fact that you don't have a user factory.

Comment: @shioyama, +1. I thought the spec/factories/users.rb with the Faker data was the factory. Is the Faker data an add on to the basic factory? Will try this approach.

Comment: Faker just fills in values, you could do the same by replacing `Faker::Name.email` by some email address, `Faker::last_name` by some last name, etc. The factory you wrote is a factory for a contact though, not a user.

Comment: @shioyama, I feel like an idiot. I changed contact to user and it passed. 'contact' was part of a snippet i used. Can't believe i missed that. If you put your prior comment in an answer I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments thread: you probably want to change `factory :contact` in your factory to `factory :user`:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do |f|
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, in your `app/spec/factories/` folder create `user.rb` and write

```
require 'factory_girl'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    lname "test12"
    fname "test12"
    ... # whatever
  end
end
```

and in your `user_spec.rb`

```
describe User do
  before { @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, :fname => "abc", :lname => "fname") }
  subject { @user }
  it { should respond_to(:fname) }
  it { should respond_to(:lname)}
  it { should be_valid }
end
```

Comment: +1 for insight gained. Will give this a shot and let you know how it works out.